# React Port 8081

Tags: reactjs, port

I'm working with React right now and I have a problem with my port,
Indeed, when I try to switch to port 8081, it doesn't do it and send me directly the port 8080, someone could help me for that please ?

I try to put all my variables on 8081 but it does not work and launch my project on 8080.

Comment: **How** do you _"try to switch to port 8081"_? Is this a CRA app, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your **package.json** file .
Your default **scripts** key must have following value .

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

Just replace your **value** of "start" key like this :
i.e add **PORT=8080**

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "PORT=8080 react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```